# Precise meaning of "wellfounded part has been transitivized"

Tags: set-theory

When discussing ultrapowers, one often says something like "we assume the wellfounded part of $M$ has been transitivized", where $M$ is some structure (say an ultrapower). What is the precise meaning of this? I understand that for a structure $(M,E)$, its wellfounded part is the class of all $x\in M$ such that there is no infinite descending $E$-sequence beginning with $x$. I also understand the Mostowski collapse lemma. What I don't understand is what one is doing precisely when one "assumes the wellfounded part of $M$ has been transitivized".
Is it: we divide $M$ into a wellfounded part and the rest, and apply Mostowski collapse to the wellfounded part, and then union the transitive isomorph with the rest?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: One technicality: If $M$ is sufficiently weird, the "rest" might contain some elements that are also in the image of the Mostowski collapse. In that case, replace the rest with an isomorphic copy that doesn't have that problem (i.e., it stays out of Mostowski's way).

Comment: @AndreasBlass That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm turning Andreas Blass's comment into an answer to move this question off the "unanswered" queue; I've made this CW to avoid reputation gain, and will delete this answer of Andreas posts one of his own.*

You are exactly right - *modulo* the subtlety that an annoying $M$ might already use one of the sets in the Mostowski-collapse-image of $M$'s well-founded part. So *first* we "relabel" everything in $M$ to avoid this, and *then* we appropriately Mostowski collapse.

Basically, all we care about is that at the end of the day we have:

> Let $X$ be the set of elements $m\in M$ such that $E\upharpoonright \{x: xEm\}$ is well-founded. Then $X$ is a transitive set and $E\upharpoonright X=\in\upharpoonright X$.